# Button not appear as press in UI when tirgger by performClick

Tags: android

i try to trigger click an button programming in `onKeyDown` function, so that i can press the key in remote control, then as if i click the button in screen. the code as below, the `onClickListener` is trigger indeed, but in UI, it seems the button `never` clicked.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ddd);

        button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ddddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        button.performClick();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean the toast message is not displayed ? Or u are enquiring about the button animations?

Comment: Try to return true instead of super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event).

Comment: @sean, toast message is displayed indeed, but no animations in UI.

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana, return true no works.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
 AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.7F);
    yourButton.startAnimation(buttonClick);
```

Comment: What will it perform ?

Comment: press effect on button

Comment: @Vinayak Mishra,  yes, your solution has press effect, but it is just alpha changes. i set the selector for the background of the button for different status, such as pressed, focused..., so i need it consistent between "Click the button" and "programming click the button"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the button state yourself when you call `performClick`, such as `button.setPressed(true)`, then change back using `button.setPressed(false)` 200ms later by:

```
    button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setPressed(false);
        }
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
myBtn.setPressed(true);
myBtn.invalidate();
```

Invalidate should cause a redraw